# I want to convert inner join Query in SubQuery

Tags: sql-server

I am using inner join in query but I want Subquery instead of join

```
select [Document No_] as DocumentNo,
       ledger.[Posting Date] as Date,
       [Sales (LCY)] as Amount,
       header.[Customer Reference] as PONo
from   [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Cust_ Ledger Entry] ledger 
  inner join [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header on ledger.[Entry No_]=header.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
where  [Customer No_] = 'DRC01' 
and    [Document Type]=2 
and    [Sales (LCY)]!=0 
and    ledger.[Posting Date] between '01/01/2019' and '12/31/2019' 
order by [Sales (LCY)] asc offset 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

[Entry No_] is foreign key in [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] with name [Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]

Comment: why do you want to convert a fast join into a slow subquery ?

Comment: Impossible to do without knowing which columns belong to which table.   And this information is not included in the question.

Comment: @GuidoG someone tells me that subquery is fast

Comment: it can be, but in most cases an inner join is faster

Comment: Is your current query experiencing a performance problem?

Comment: also be carefull when using between. Read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to drop the join and use a subquery instead,
it will look something like this.

Since you did not use an table alias for all columns, I had to assume that no other column of table in the subquery is used anywhere else. If that is not the case then this will not work

It will also only work if the subquery returns no more then 1 row, otherwise a subquery cannot be used at all

```
select [Document No_] as DocumentNo,
       ledger.[Posting Date] as Date,
       [Sales (LCY)] as Amount,
       ( select header.[Customer Reference] 
         from  [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header 
         where ledger.[Entry No_] = header.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
       ) as PONo
from   [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Cust_ Ledger Entry] ledger 
where  [Customer No_] = 'DRC01' 
and    [Document Type]=2 
and    [Sales (LCY)]!=0 
and    ledger.[Posting Date] between '01/01/2019' and '12/31/2019' 
order by [Sales (LCY)] asc 
offset 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```